# Repopulating select after ajax request

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I have a select which allows the user to select multiple option. Also on the same page is a form that will allow the user to add new keywords which will appear in the select.

My javascript sends an ajax request to a php script which either returns a success or error message which then gets added to the dom.

The ajax part of the script looks like this

```
$.post(
        metadataAction,
        {
            dateOfUpdate:dateOfUpdateVal,
            metadataStandardName:metadataStandardNameVal,
            metadataLanguage:metadataLanguageVal
        },
        function(responseText) {
            $('body').append(responseText);
        },
        "html"
);
```

I only want to repopulate the options when a new keyword has been successfully added.

Does anyone have any suggestions on the best way to achieve this?

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0):

```
$.post(
        metadataAction,
        {
            dateOfUpdate:dateOfUpdateVal,
            metadataStandardName:metadataStandardNameVal,
            metadataLanguage:metadataLanguageVal
        },
        function(responseText) {
            $('body').append(responseText);
            $('#select_id').append('<option>'+responseText+'</option>');
        },
        "html"
);
```

Answer (score 0):

looks a bit strange that you are appending the message to the body, but anyhow..

return a JSON string representing an object with two properties:success[bool],message[string]
don't have experience with php, but if the response will be of type JSON, then jQuery(1.4.2)
will parse it as an object and then in your success function:

```
function(data)
{
  if(data.success)
  {
    //append the item
  }
  //show the message
  $(msgCont).text(data.message)
}
```

note that you will always get to the success function if the response status code is 200(or any other 2XX)

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. The response that gets appended is a fixed positon div which then get's faded out after a few seconds so appending it to the body makes sense. I like the idea of returning a json object. I could then also include the updated options to update the select. Thanks

Comment: if a user appends a lot of items, you can have the fixed positioned div already hidden on page, and just change it's text and hide it away after each operation. this is a more clean way to handle your case since you don't want to return a json string that also contains raw html tags(+ more bytes to transfer.. but this is really beeing picky ;-))

Answer (score 0):

To solve this I have the php script output a json object.

If the addition was successful the json has three properties.

Success, message and newSelect. I check for the occurrence of success in my ajax response. If it is present I use the jquery method replaceWith() to update the select currently in the form with the one returned.

Thanks for the help.